# Did something change WRT ServiceBehavior.IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults?

Tags: .net, wcf, servicebehavior

I have the feeling that something changed in WCF 4.5 with regards to the IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults flag. I am usually pretty diligent about defining fault messages, mapping them to exceptions and handling all exceptions at the WCF surface by logging, map e.g. XyzException to an XyzFault and then throwing FaultException<XyzFault>. For the purpose I use the Enterprize Library's WCF exception handling app. block. My believe was that if you set IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true you will simply get more info about the exception, incl. the call stack, the inner exception, etc. Also you get more generic FaultExceptions for not handled exceptions (which I always treated as a bug.) And if you set the flag to false the additional information is gone and that's it. However, today I ran some integration tests and all negative tests failed because instead of getting the expected FaultException<XyzFaul> I am getting FaultException<ExceptionDetail>. When I turned the flag to false, voila - I get what I expected in a first place.

Was I wrong in my expectations or something changed?

Comment: When includeExceptionDetailsInFaults=true an unhandled exception on server side is being thrown as FaultException<ExceptionDetail> and in case it is false it is being thrown as FaultException. I verified the same behavior exists in both 4.0 & 4.5. And if you throw FaultException<XyzFault> at server side i see it is being received as FaultException<XyzFault> irrespective of the value of includeExceptionDetails flag. FaultException<ExceptionDetail> generally means an unhandled exception. Could you try adding tracing (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) (continued..)

Comment: (continued..)to see if there are any exceptions in the svclog file. If you could still reproduce the issue could you send us an email to netfx45compat at microsoft.com?

Comment: Praburaj, thank you for your comment and offer to help. I think I found the problem: I was setting the flag in ServiceBehaviorAttribute object instead of in ServiceDebugBehavior object and now it works as I expected. Could you please explain what is the difference between the two flags. Thank you!

Comment: Defining in the ServiceBehaviorAttribute should be the same as defining in the ServiceDebugBehavior(web.config) except the scope. Setting in attribute is scoped only to the service definition where this is decorated. But specifying in web.config can have higher scope based on how many services defined in the config use this behavior. If you have set this in an unnamed service behavior then all services in the project will have this. I noticed the behavior has not changed in 4.5 from this aspect as well. So if you had accessed a service where this flag was not set then you might see this issue.